# how to find out the element which does not contain any class?

Tags: javascript

How to find out the element

which does not contain any class?

```
<p>You will receive the ebook in your email</p>
<p class="active">You will NOT receive the ebook in your email</p>
```

I want to find the paragraph element which does not contain **any class**.
Sample code is much appreciated.
Keep Coding...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo class:

```js
let matches = document.querySelectorAll('p:not([class])');

for (let p of matches) {
    console.log(p.textContent);
}
```

```html
<p>You will receive the ebook in your email</p>
<p class="active">You will NOT receive the ebook in your email</p>
```

If you want to also match elements that have the `class` attribute, but which is still empty, then add that in the selector: `p:not([class]), p[class=""]`. Of course, you can then also think of a `class` attribute that has just space(s), ...etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could filter your paragraphs by the length of their classList

```js
var allParagraphs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("p")).filter(({classList}) => classList.length === 0)

console.log(allParagraphs)

//for older browsers

var allP = [];

document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(function(el) {
   if(el.classList.length === 0) allP.push(el);
})

console.log(allP);
```

```html
<p>no class</p>
<p>nope</p>
<p class="df">öldskjf</p>
<p class="ölsdf">slkdf </p>
```